# aggregate points under a distance java

Tags: java, graph, nodes, aggregation

I have a set of WGS84 points which I want to combine based on a distance threshold in order to get an "average point".

My points are defined as points with

Now, I am iterating through the whole list of points and estimating the distance:

```
List<Point> Nodes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int k=0;k<nNodes;k++){
   for (int o=k+0;o<nNodes;o++){
      double lat1 = nodes.get(k).getX;
      double lat2 = nodes.get(o).getX;
      double lon1 = nodes.get(k).getY;
      double lon2 = nodes.get(o).getY;
      double inbetweenDistance = dist(lat1,  lng1,  lat2,  lng2);
   }
}
```

What would be an efficient way to identify nodes which have a distance (between two nodes) less than i.e. 50 meters and create a new set of (isolated) nodes and aggregated nodes?

For example in the following picture nodes 1,2,3,4 could be combined in one "aggregated" node, while node 5 and 6 cannot as the distance between them is not smaller than 50 meters.

[image: Nodes]

It would be nice if the aggregated node would be attributed the average(X) and average(Y) of nodes 1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: I'm sorry Manos C but I didn't understand the question, what do you mean by "distance less than" , do you mean distance between any two points or the summed distance while iterating over points or the average ?

Comment: and what do you mean by "supernodes" ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt response, I mean the distance between two nodes. I call (maybe vaguely) supernodes the aggregated nodes.

Comment: well it's not going to be very easy, I think maybe you need two lists, one to aggregate nodes and the other the full list, but then there are many complex cases like a shared node between two aggregated groups

Comment: sorry Manos C but I don't think your question can have a good short answer

Comment: I figured it out, thank you very much and I have implemented it using some lists. I was thinking if there was some library or a piece of code that it would do this in a more efficient way.